# cycles bake seems to have lost some UV data

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, baking

I have modelled and textured a simple object using separate materials on the different parts of the object.  I then created a separate texture and baked diffuse AO and normal all saved as separate textures using a 2nd UV map.
This all worked fine.  I then deleted all the materials and the original UV map.
I created a new material with just one texture (the baked diffuse of all the sub materials) This material only seems to map to the UVs of the last sub material I deleted the rocks and grass. In edit mode I can see the UV mapping seems to include all faces.[image: blend snip 1]
here is the object in edit mode with all faces selected......

[image]

Have I missed something obvious with assigning the UVs ??
As you can see in the top rendered view only the rocks and grass on the ground  show the texture . In the lower image all faces appear to have correct uvs so why is the texture not appearing on all faces in the rendered view ?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend (with packed textures?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved..........
Even though I deleted all the sub materials that I baked into the one texture,  the material slots were still there.
Once I deleted all the no longer required sub material slots the face textures appeared as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the top render I can read the word mail on the box, so I think the texture is there, you just need some more lights so it shows.